# Is it acceptable to `const_cast<Foo*>(this)` if public state doesn't change?

Tags: c++, constants, c++20

I have a C++ class that calculates some statistic parameters on the go. Is it acceptable to cast away const from `this` to implement caching of lengthy computations, if I don't change publicly visible state, and `const` function in question is idempotent and pure/referentially transparent?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>

class Compute {
public:
    Compute() = default;
    ~Compute() = default;

    void add(int x) {
        sum += x;
        squareDirty = true;
    }

    int getSquare() const {
        if (squareDirty) {
            auto &mthis = *const_cast<Compute*>(this);
            usleep(2000); // takes a long time!
            mthis.squareCached = sum * sum;
            mthis.squareDirty = false;
        }

        return squareCached;
    }

private:
    int sum = 0;
    bool squareDirty = false;
    int squareCached;
};

void foo() {
    Compute c{};
    c.add(10);
    c.add(20);
    printf("%d\n", c.getSquare()); // long time...
    printf("%d\n", c.getSquare()); // fast!
}
```

I want to lazily compute things only when they are actually needed — and cache them until new data arrives.

However, *caching* things means that my `T getSquare() const` method would have to cast away `const` from `this` to mutate private state.

But as `getSquare` is effectively idempotent, compiler can compute it once and store as constant, or inline, or do whatever else, as my private state is discardable.

Is this an acceptable thing to do, or am I asking for UB?

Comment: Why not just make the cache related variables `mutable`?

Comment: I wasn't even aware of existence of `mutable` :) It seems that it's exactly what I need! Can you please post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved by using the `mutable` keyword. This keyword indicates that the member variable can be modified in a `const` qualified function:

```
struct S
{
  mutable int x;  // some data that is not relevant to users of the object (e.g. a cache variable)
  int y;

  void f() const 
  {
     x = 42;  // fine 
     y = 42;  // error
  }
};
```

This is a much better way to modify variables in a const qualified function, than either giving up const-correctness, or using `const_cast` (which is a potential source of UB).

Note that when you make a function `const`, you actually guarantee something more than "the visible state is not changed". You are guaranteeing that accesses to an object via any const functions are thread-safe. This means that if you have `mutable` variables, you should think carefully about their state, if multiple threads might access them simultaneously. You should probably consider manually synchronizing accesses to this variable yourself in that case.

Comment: While it is generally a good idea to do so, const does not guarantee access is thread safe.  It is somewhat true for the standard library, although all bets are off when user code is called (```std::function<...>::operator()(...) const``` being the canonical example).

Comment: @Nevin I'm not sure I follow; isn't thread-safety guaranteed by the programmer when they make a function const?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it acceptable to `const_cast<Foo*>(this)` if public state doesn't change?

It is undefined behaviour to modify non-mutable state of a const object.

For that reason, it is not acceptable to modify non-mutable state through a reference to const after const cast unless it is provable that the referred object is non-const.

Whether that state is public is irrelevant. This type of transparent caching is the reason why mutable members exist, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
auto &mthis = *const_cast<Compute*>(this);
mthis.squareCached = sum * sum;
mthis.squareDirty = false;
```

can cause undefined behavior. It depends on how the original object was constructed.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast:

> Modifying a `const` object through a non-`const` access path and referring to a `volatile` object through a non-`volatile` glvalue results in undefined behavior.

It will be better to make the relevant members `mutable`.

```
int sum = 0;
mutable bool squareDirty = false;
mutable int squareCached;
```

Then, you may use:

```
int getSquare() const {
    if (squareDirty) {
        usleep(2000); // takes a long time!
        this->squareCached = sum * sum;
        this->squareDirty = false;
    }

    return squareCached;
}
```

without fear of undefined behavior.

Comment: To be precise, the cast itself does not cause any undefined behavior. It's the _modification_ of the _supposedly_ `const` object (the same applies to `volatile`) that can lead to undefined behavior.